# .Contains() in .Any() EF Core 6 doesn't work and gives crash of unsupported client evaluation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a query which used to work fine in Entity Framework but when we migrated to EF Core 6.0 it crashes due to unsupported client evaluation, I think it's something with contains inside Any () but I am not sure exactly. Below is query:

```cs
var fixedAnnuityQuotes = (from quo in context.FixedAnnuityQuoteHistories
                            where quo.OrganizationId == organizationID
                            select new { quo });

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(globalSearch))
{
    fixedAnnuityQuotes = fixedAnnuityQuotes.Where(x => new []
    {
        x.quo.ContactId!=null? x.quo.Contact.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + (x.quo.Contact.MiddleName!=null? x.quo.Contact.MiddleName.ToLower():"") + " " + x.quo.Contact.LastName.ToLower():
        x.quo.AssignedToUserId!=null?   x.quo.AssignedToUser.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + (x.quo.AssignedToUser.MiddleName!=null? x.quo.AssignedToUser.MiddleName.ToLower():"") + " " + x.quo.AssignedToUser.LastName.ToLower():"",
        x.quo.JointContactId!=null? x.quo.JointContact.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + (x.quo.JointContact.MiddleName!=null? x.quo.JointContact.MiddleName.ToLower():"") + " " + x.quo.JointContact.LastName.ToLower():
        x.quo.JointAssignedToUserId!=null?   x.quo.JointAssignedToUser.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + (x.quo.JointAssignedToUser.MiddleName!=null? x.quo.JointAssignedToUser.MiddleName.ToLower():"") + " " + x.quo.JointAssignedToUser.LastName.ToLower():"",

    }.Any(s => s.Contains(globalSearch.ToLower())));
}
int totalRecords = fixedAnnuityQuotes.Count();
```

In above line to get count crash happens. Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Creating an array inside a query expression isn't supported. EF-core 2 auto-switched to client-side evaluation in such cases. That was abandoned in v3, fortunately. You'll have to do the `Contains` 4 times. Also, since it will be evaluated database-side, you can remove most null checks.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for providing the information, just a quick clarification this will happen only due to array or will happen even if I change array to a list of string or anything.

Comment: More precisely, creating an array (or List) is possible, but calling `.Contains` on it is not supported.